# I cant use DVDFab on my netbook

Tags: laptop

Does anyone know how to change the size of the opening page in DVDFab so I can use the start button. At the moment it is hiding beneath the start bar flap.  I can move it around the screen but can not minimize it at all.

Comment: Netbooks, the bane of all computer users. . .

Answer (score 1):

When the window is selected, press the alt+space key together, then press M. You can then use the arrow keys to re-position the window on screen.

If it consistently appears off screen, you could potentially right click the program shortcut in the Start Menu or wherever you launch it from, choose Properties and under the Run section choose Maximised, this will ensure your program will fill the screen upon every launch.